# Point existing domain to wordpress MU site on another server

Tags: wordpress, mapping, dns, external, mu

How do we point existing domain to wordpress MU site on another server? Here's the setup.

1. Server A has WPMU installed, with network setup of subfolders. www.wpmuinstall.com/site1
2. Server B has a domain hosted on it.. www.clientdomain.com
3. We want to point www.clientdomain.com from ServerB to ServerA www.wpmuinstall.com/site123

If above is not possible, we can switch to site1.wpmuinstall.com but then how do we point this site1.wpmuinstall.com to the siteid1 ? We have the WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin installed but the WPMU is still setup as subfolders.

Please advise on how to accomplish client domain pointing to our wpmu site. Ideally we want to  setup something like wordpress.com with custom domains pointing to subsites.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with paths, install [Wordpress Domain Mapping plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) and follow the steps described on [this article](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/). It will let you map a domain to a path in your server.

If you are using subdomains, then:

1. Add the desired subdomain to a site.
2. Point www.clientdomain.com to your wordpress server.
3. On your server, add the domain www.clientdomain.com and make it point to your wordpress installation.
4. Wait until DNS changes take effect.
5. Your site should be ready.

Comment: Wordpress domain mapping plugin only works to point Wordpress sites outside to some external domain. This is opposite of what I am looking for. I want to point external domain to wordpress MU site.

Comment: That's the 2 step for, to point the external domain to the wordpress MU site.